# Boxy modal plugin back button showing again after form submit

Tags: jquery, submit, modal-dialog, back-button, boxy

I am using the boxy jquery plugin to display my modal forms.
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

On the page i spawn the modal that contains a form that is submitting to itself like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('.boxy').boxy({modal: true, closeText: '', draggable: false, unloadOnHide:      true});
    });
</script>

<div class="reportPop hiddenContent" id="reportPop">
    <form action="" method="post" name="reportContent">
        <p><?php echo $t_report_content_message_text; ?></p>
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" name="reported_item_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="Question" name="reported_type" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="question_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="report_content" />
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $t_report_question;?>" />
    </form>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I have all of the functionality working for the form submit  but once i submit the form and try to use the back  button, it shows the modal again which is not the desired experience. Looking to just see the page before without the modal open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just added the boxy call js code

Answer (score 0):

I guess hidding the form when submitting the form will solve your problem
try this code please :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('.boxy').boxy({modal: true, closeText: '', draggable: false, unloadOnHide:      true});
        $('#myForm').submit(function(){
            var self = $(this);
            $('#reportPop').hide("normal",function(){
                self.submit();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="reportPop hiddenContent" id="reportPop">
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" name="reportContent">
        <p><?php echo $t_report_content_message_text; ?></p>
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" name="reported_item_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="Question" name="reported_type" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" name="question_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="report_content" />
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $t_report_question;?>" />
    </form>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are using like the code above so the modal will show on every visit of this page! is it the case ?

Comment: No, it is only shown when the link is clicked to show the modal that has the boxy class on it. The issue is only happening when i submit the form and then hit the back button

Comment: This is still not working. Actually adding the return false; is stopping the form from submitting. Removing this part is still making the same end result when i click the back button.